# removing duplicate row from mysql where value equals something

Tags: php, mysql

I've all the way to the end of the internet and I'm proper stuck. Whilst I can find partial answer I'm unable to modify it to make it work.

I have a table named **`myfetcher`** like:

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| fid_id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| linksetid   | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| url         | varchar(200) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The `url` field would sometimes contain dupes but rather than remove all duplicates in the table, I need only where the field `linksetid` is equal to `X`.

The SQL below removes all duplicates in the table (which is not what I want)... but what I want is only the duplicates within a set range in the field `linksetid`. I know I'm doing something wrong, just not sure what is it.

```sql
DELETE FROM myfetcher USING myfetcher, myfetcher as vtable 
WHERE (myfetcher.fid>vtable.fid)
  AND (myfetcher.url=vtable.url)
  AND (myfetcher.linksetid='$linkuniq')
```

Comment: Just to be clear, if you have 2 rows with equal linksetid, you want both of them deleted (not just one of them) right?

Comment: Sorry,I need only one copy remaining..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete only records with linksetid=X. First EXISTS check case when all records are with linksetid=X then only one with min(fid) remains. The second EXISTS check case when there is a record with linksetid<>X then all records with linksetid=X will be removed:

**NOTE:** this query works in Oracle or MSSQL. For MYSql use next workaround:

```
DELETE FROM myfetcher 
where (myfetcher.linksetid='$linkuniq')
      and 
      (
      exists
      (select t.fid from myfetcher t where 
                 t.fid<myfetcher.fid 
                 and 
                 t.url=myfetcher.url
                 and 
                 t.linksetid='$linkuniq')

      or 

      exists
      (select t.fid from myfetcher t where 
                 t.url=myfetcher.url
                 and 
                 t.linksetid<>'$linkuniq')
       )
```

In MYSql you [can't use update/delete command with subquery for the target table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause). So for MySql you can use following script. [SqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a246/1):

```
create table to_delete_tmp as 
select fid from myfetcher as tmain 
     where (tmain.linksetid='$linkuniq')
      and 
      (
      exists
      (select t.fid from myfetcher t where 
                 t.fid<tmain.fid
                 and 
                 t.url=tmain.url
                 and 
                 t.linksetid='$linkuniq')

      or 

      exists
      (select t.fid from myfetcher t where 
                 t.url=tmain.url
                 and 
                 t.linksetid<>'$linkuniq')
       ) ;

delete from myfetcher where myfetcher.fid in (select fid from to_delete_tmp);

drop table to_delete_tmp;
```

Comment: Sql tells me 
'You can't specify target table 'myfetcher' for update in FROM clause'

Comment: Please look at the fixed answer. I added a script to use in MySQL to avoid this error.

Comment: Thanks for your help but your script is not exactly doing what I want.  It should remove duplicates within a certain range and leave one remaining. Currently it simply deletes everything at the given [id] that already exist in the table.